# How do i take user input and store it successfully in an ArrayList? Then how do i get my program to show me all the elements in the ArrayList?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I want a program that stores details about staff in an arraylist. I'd like to prompt user for input and store each result in the arraylist. How do I do this? And how do i view everything stored in the arraylist after?
It doesn't need to reflect the code I have, just can't seem to figure out how i have a class with setters and getters and then create a new main class promting user for input and store that input in the arraylist.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class salesPersonMain {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InputValidationException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //ask user for input and get input
        System.out.println("Enter id: ");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter first name:");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter last name:");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();
        //save in array list
        List<salesPerson> sPerson = new ArrayList<salesPerson>();

        sPerson.add(new salesPerson(id, firstName, lastName));

    }
}

I have another class for the salesperson:

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class salesPerson<sPerson> {
    //create variables for sales person
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
 public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) throws InputValidationException {
        if (firstName.matches("\\p{Upper}(\\p{Lower}){2,20}")) {
        } else {
            throw new InputValidationException();
        }
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)throws InputValidationException {
        if (lastName.matches("\\p{Upper}(\\p{Lower}){2,20}")) {
        } else {
            throw new InputValidationException();
        }
        {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
 //creates array of salespeople
        private ArrayList<sPerson> salesPerson;

        public salesPerson() {
            salesPerson = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        //adds new salesperson to the array
        public void add(salesPerson sPerson) {
            salesPerson.add((sPerson) sPerson);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a loop to repeatedly get the input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InputValidationException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<salesPerson> sPerson = new ArrayList<salesPerson>();

    // Loop forever
    // Need a way to break the loop. One option: have the user
    // input "q" for quit
    while (true) {

        //ask user for input and get input
        System.out.println("Enter id ('q' to quit): ");
        String temp = input.nextLine();
        if (temp.equals("q")) break;

        int id = Integer.parseInt(temp);
           // This should be in try/catch in case parseInt fails

        System.out.println("Enter first name:");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter last name:");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();

        //save in array list
        sPerson.add(new salesPerson(id, firstName, lastName));
    }

    // Print the list
    sPerson.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

So it prints out properly, you need to override the `toString` function in the `salesPerson` class:

```
public class salesPerson {
    // Other code here.....

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + "," + firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I still need the array part of code in my salesPerson class? or just in the salesPersonMain? And how do I print everything in the array to check it's saving? 
 Thanks!

Comment: @JayMac No, the `salesPerson` class should not have a list. It is meant to represent just one `salesPerson`.  If you are using Java 8, you can print the list with `sPerson.forEach(System.out::println);` after the `while` loop. You should override the `String toString()` function in the `salesPerson` class.

Comment: @JayMac YW. Since you are new here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)